# Pandas groupby select top N rows based on column value AND group size share

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data:

```
    group   cluster probabilityA    probabilityB
0   a   0   0.28    0.153013
1   a   0   0.28    0.133686
2   a   0   0.28    0.058366
3   a   0   0.28    0.091937
4   a   1   0.50    0.040095
5   a   1   0.50    0.150359
6   a   2   0.32    0.043512
7   a   2   0.32    0.088408
8   a   2   0.32    0.005158
9   a   2   0.32    0.107054
10  a   2   0.32    0.029050
11  a   2   0.32    0.099361
12  b   0   0.40    0.057752
13  b   0   0.40    0.177103
14  b   1   0.60    0.218634
15  b   1   0.60    0.098535
16  b   1   0.60    0.065746
17  b   1   0.60    0.190805
18  b   1   0.60    0.191425
```

What I want to do, is to select top 5 (arbitrary number, can be N) of rows per each group based on `probabilityB` AND on the share of the sizes of every `cluster`. If we only look at group `a`, there are 3 clusters: 0, 1 and 2. Their respective size shares are:

```
group  cluster
a      0          0.333333
       1          0.166667
       2          0.500000
Name: probabilityA, dtype: float64
```

And here, if I want top 5 rows based on this shares I would take

```py
(round
      (df
            .groupby(["group", "cluster"])["probabilityA"]
            .count() / 
       df
            .groupby(["group", "cluster"])["probabilityA"]
            .count()
            .sum(level = 0) 
       * 5)

group  cluster
a      0          2.0
       1          1.0
       2          2.0
```

2 elements from cluster 0 and 2, and only 1 element from cluster 1 based on `probabilityB` column.
So, my result will look like this (index is irrelevant in the sample below):

```
    group   cluster probabilityA    probabilityB
0   a   1   0.50    0.150359
1   a   2   0.32    0.107054
2   a   2   0.32    0.088408
3   a   0   0.28    0.153013
4   a   0   0.28    0.133686
5   b   0   0.40    0.177103
6   b   1   0.60    0.218634
7   b   1   0.60    0.191425
8   b   1   0.60    0.190805
9   b   1   0.60    0.098535
```

Is there a way I can achieve it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think, the most clear solution is to divide tke task into steps:

1. Generate counts for each top-level group:

   ```
   c1 = df.groupby(["group"])["probabilityA"].count().rename('c1')
   ```

   For your data, the result is:

   ```
   group
   a    12
   b     7
   Name: c1, dtype: int64
   ```
2. Set the number of rows to take from each top-level group:

   ```
   N = 5
   ```
3. Generate the counts of rows to take from each second-level group:

   ```
   cnt = df.groupby(["group", "cluster"])["probabilityA"].count().rename('c2')\
       .reset_index(level=1).join(c1).set_index('cluster', append=True)\
       .apply(lambda row: N * row.c2 / row.c1, axis=1).round().astype(int)
   ```

   For your data, the result is:

   ```
   group  cluster
   a      0          2
          1          1
          2          2
   b      0          1
          1          4
   dtype: int32
   ```
4. Then define the function, retutning the respective number of "top" rows:

   ```
   def takeFirst(grp):
       grpKey = tuple(grp.iloc[0, 0:2])
       grpCnt = cnt.loc[grpKey]
       return grp.nlargest(grpCnt, 'probabilityB')
   ```
5. And the last step is to compute the result:

   ```
   df.groupby(['group', 'cluster']).apply(takeFirst)
   ```

   For your data, the result is:

   ```
                    group  cluster  probabilityA  probabilityB
   group cluster                                              
   a     0       0      a        0          0.28      0.153013
                 1      a        0          0.28      0.133686
         1       5      a        1          0.50      0.150359
         2       9      a        2          0.32      0.107054
                 11     a        2          0.32      0.099361
   b     0       13     b        0          0.40      0.177103
         1       14     b        1          0.60      0.218634
                 18     b        1          0.60      0.191425
                 17     b        1          0.60      0.190805
                 15     b        1          0.60      0.098535
   ```

I delibarately left *group* and *cluster* as index columns, to ease
the identification from which group they were taken, but in the final
version you can append `.reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)` to drop
them.

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to include also `probabilityA` into the consideration when returning the `nlargest`? in some cases I have more than 5 clusters, which will make this not sufficient. I want to take from top5 of `probabilityA` clusters the top `probabilityB` based on their shares

Comment: This is rather material for **another** question.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you groupby ProbabilityA - you might be able to achieve this.

```
df.groupby(['group', 'cluster', 'probabilityA']).aggregate({
    'group': 'first',
    'cluster': 'first',
    'probabilityA': lambda x: round(len(x)/(sum(x)*(len(x))*n),
    'probabilityB': lambda x: sum(x)
})
```

> The solution above was faulty because count().sum() is different on overall groupby and on probabilityA alone separately, which is why I did the following:
>
> **UPDATE** - Full Solution:

1. Sort your dataframe:

```
df.sort_values(by=['group', 'cluster','probabilityB'], ascending=False)
```

2. Create Counts of Objects in a separate grouped dataframe:

```
cluster = pd.DataFrame(round(df.groupby(['group', 'cluster', 'probabilityA'])['probabilityA'].count() 
          / df.groupby(['group', 'cluster', 'probabilityA'])['probabilityB'].count().sum(level=0)*5))
cluster.reset_index(level=['group', 'cluster', 'probabilityA'], inplace=True)
cluster = cluster.rename(columns={0: 'counts'})
cluster['counts'] = pd.to_numeric(cluster['counts'], downcast='integer')
```

3. Create New Dataframe with Sort ProbabilityB:

```
output = pd.concat(cluster.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df['group'] == x['group']) & (df['cluster'] == x['cluster'])].groupby(
    ['group', 'cluster']).head(x['counts']), axis=1).tolist())
```

Output:
[See Output DataFrame Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJuZE.png)

Comment: are you sure that this code is running? Even after fixing brackets, it does not run

Comment: Hi! I tested it out here and it works for me: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rIEMHN1Ef2Z_Kkp3znXdrWVv1tUqtK9C

Comment: this does not take into account the data I have. You have not used it at all

Comment: In order for me to use it - you need to upload the data in a .csv or Pandas Readable Format. The one youve used above is skewed and unusable raw. You can also edit this notebook and test it out with the dataset yourself.

Comment: You can select and copy the data and then use `pd.read_clipboard()` which I have used to paste this data here